# Problems with Exact Diagonalization Implementation in Quantum System Evolution

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, hamiltonian

I've been trying to implement exact diagonalization to study the time evolution of quantum states and subsequently compute local magnetizations. I have written functions for evolving the state and computing the local magnetization, but the results I'm getting are not aligning with my expectations. I'm wondering if there might be a mistake in the implementation or if I've misunderstood the exact diagonalization method.

Here's a breakdown of my code:

```
def time_evolved_state(eigenvalues, eigenvectors, t, psi):
    coeffs = np.dot(np.conj(eigenvectors.T), psi.data)
    time_evolved_phases = np.exp(-1j * eigenvalues * t)
    evolved_state_data = np.dot(eigenvectors, coeffs * time_evolved_phases)
    return Statevector(evolved_state_data)

def sigma_z_operator(j):
    I = Pauli(label='I').to_matrix()
    sigma_z = Pauli(label='Z').to_matrix()
    operators = [I] * N_qubit
    operators[j] = sigma_z
    from functools import reduce
    return Operator(reduce(np.kron, operators))

def local_magnetization(j, evolved_state):
    magnetization_val = np.real(evolved_state.expectation_value(sigma_z_operator(j))) # In basis of 0 and 1
    return magnetization_val




eigenvalues, eigenvectors = LA.eigh(Matrix)
j = Site - 1  # Make sure to specify the value of 'Site'
t_values = np.linspace(0, time, num=num_points) # Define 'time' and 'num_points'
magnetizations = [local_magnetization(j, time_evolved_state(eigenvalues, eigenvectors, t, psi)) for t in t_values]
```

Is there an issue with my exact diagonalization implementation? Or have I possibly misunderstood some aspect of the method or the physics?

Thanks in advance!!!